# Is it possible to query transactions from a smart contract by certain attributes?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I have a smart contract which is storing payment data. At the end of the day it is called to store how much money was spent from me. Is there a way to go through every transaction so that I can collect this data and use it? For example I want to go through every day in the month, retrieve the spendings and make a final report for the month.

Here is an image of all the transaction data:[image]

Is it possible to go back in the past and open every transaction to see its data, for example by writing the index or the transaction hash or age of execution? At the moment I see that I can read only the data from the very last appended transaction at position 0.

Comment: Are you searching for input params of historic transactions? Or event logs emitted by these transactions? Or historic storage values (in that case is the current data retrievable by a `view` function or is it just a private property)? ... There are slightly different approaches for all these things.

Comment: Hello, honestly I don’t know which approach I should use. Can you send me some links where I can see some examples of your proposal? I don’t use event logs but it is actually a smart way to query. Do you have an example? I am still new in Solidity and now trying to learn those things. My idea is to somehow go back in the transactions for example by day and see what has been stored inside(extract the parameters). If you think that input parameters are easy, I am also open to learn that too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to go back in the past and open every transaction to see its data, for example by writing the index or the transaction hash or age of execution?

Yes it is possible. What you are describing is indexing chain data. You can write your own signature filters (For the function that is important to you) and define block ranges (start, end). You probably also want to check the bloom filters and skip most block transactions if you are on a busy chain to speed up the process. A friend wrote a generic tool in python that can do this -> https://pypi.org/project/eth-monitor/ (You will still have to write your own filter). If you function emits events with the important details, you could also filter the events with something like Ethers.js -> https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-queryFilter

Alternatively you can use existing 3rd party service like TheGraph or even EtherScan if you trust their indexing.